# How do I locate sprinkler heads on a winterized system so contractor doesn't damage them?

Tags: sprinkler-system

I have a contractor that will be doing work in my yard. I would like to locate and mark the sprinkler heads for them so they don't get damaged. How can I do that if my system is already winterized? Can I turn the system on for the heads to pop up and then shut right off?

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, using ordinary tap water as a Sprinkler Operating Fluid really causes problems sometimes. As an alternative try Atmospheric Blend, colloquially referred to as "compressed air." It'll pop the sprinkler heads up just the same as ordinary tap water but without the unpleasant "frozen pipes" and "mud" side effects that always follow use of tap water in the winter.

If your sprinkler system is not too large, and your air compressor is not too small, you may be able to get it done with what you already have. Something with a tank on the order of 11 gallons can kinda-sorta get the job done. Otherwise, the smallest towable air compressor you can find at a tool rental center will provide more than enough air for operating just about any residential sprinkler system.

The setup is fairly ad-hoc: look at your system, choose a place where you can break into the piping by opening an existing connection (at a union for example), then go to the hardware/plumbing store and find an assortment of fittings to adapt from your air hose to the sprinkler system. Then blow air in. I suggest keeping the pressure low, 40-60 psi, because the sudden hammer of 100 psi hitting a valve or sprinkler has more potential for causing damage.

Comment: Even using a smaller air compressor might work, as the op wouldn't need to actually blow out the lines, but to just cause enough disturbance around the heads that they can be seen where they are

Comment: @whatsisname That's a really good point. In fact even just the sound of air escaping may be enough to identify their locations.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to flood your blown-out system in the middle of winter.  You'll have to blow it out again, and by the time you do that there may be spots that freeze and damage some heads or valves.

If the contractor is not digging up your whole yard too extensively it's probably cheaper and less risky to just take the chance that some pipes will get cut, and fix them in the spring.  Fixing one or two cut pipes is a relatively minor thing compared to blowing out your system a second time and replacing several damaged heads.

If the contractor *is* digging up your whole yard extensively, you probably should wait til spring to turn on the system and let the contractor plan their work including where to dig by hand.

Answer (score 2):

While it's understandable that your contractor won't know where to look, you should have a reasonably decent idea of where the sprinklers are so it shouldn't take you too long to just walk through the yard, find the heads, and mark them with little flags like the ones that the utility companies (or utility marking companies) use. They sell the flags (just plain, no corporate markings) at most big-box stores.

I'm pretty sure the colors have meaning, so maybe pick up some extra flagging to tie around the stakes so you can identify your markings to the contractor from the general utility markings that are already going down. You did remember to call the "before you dig" number for your area (811 for most, if not all, of the US) so the contractor doesn't hit power or gas lines, right?

Obviously, there's piping running between the heads - if you know the layout, put a few flags in the ground to indicate where the lines are. If you don't know, well, you're probably going to have a damaged pipe or two. Based on what I've read on other questions here, it's not terribly difficult to repair them in the spring before you turn the water back on.

Comment: I don't know if it's universal but in the two places I've lived, homeowner's color for marking spots in the yard is White. Blue = water, sewer. Yellow = gas. Red = electric. Orange = telecom. If marking this way, I'd recommend marking the heads with flags but doing the line locations (if known) with paint instead of flagging.

Comment: In theory, @FredricShope, blue would work since this is water, but I fully get your point that that is understood to be for mains & house supply. Fair point about paint, too, but a line of flags, explained to the contractor would work, I'd think. I've seen them in packs of 50 or more - there will be plenty and that saves buying a can of spray paint...

Comment: @FredricShope for clarification- you have all your colors right except sewer which is typically green.  Official colors (in US at least):  Red=Power; Yellow=Gas,Oil,Steam; Orange=Communications; Blue=Water (potable); Purple=Reclaimed Water, Green=Sewer,Storm Drain; Pink=Survey markings; White=Proposed dig area